# IQueryable does not contain ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

My view's model is an `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` so in my controller I do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult show() {
    IQueryable query= from data in entity.dbCtxt
        select data;
    return PartialView("show", query.ToList());
}
```

Turns out `IQueryable` does not contain the definition of `ToList()`...

```
public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable{
     Type ElementType { get; }
     Expression Expression { get; }
     IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}
```

How do I cast `IQueryable` into a list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `ToList` is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`, not `IQueryable`. if that is your query, you can simply do this:

```
public PartialViewResult show() {

        return PartialView("show", dbCtxt.YourDbSet.ToList());
}
```

`DbSet<T>` class inherits from `IQueryable<T>`, so if you idea is to fetch all the rows of that table, you can call `ToList` directly from your `DbSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need it to be `Iqueryable` but you can just do this, since `select` will return a `IEnumerable<T>` you can call `ToList()` on that

```
        var query = from data in entity.dbCtxt
                   select data;
        return PartialView("show", query.ToList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `new` to your select statement. Refer here [Data Transformations with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/data-transformations-with-linq)

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult show() {
    var query = 
        from data in entity.dbCtxt
        select new { data };
    return PartialView("show", query.ToList());
}
```